# Sharing access to Google Bigquery datasets

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a project and a dataset in Bigquery. I can share the dataset with other developers but I cannot share the project. I get a 404 error when I click the "Team" link on the left pane. Is there a work around to share the project?

Comment: Emre, are you sure you are using the same account you used when you created the Project?

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes, it's the same account. Other developers can view see the dataset on the left pane too but they are not allowed to query it. I thought, I could set some permissions from the Team link but that link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 9):

Dataset sharing in BQ is a little unintuitive - the actual sharing is pretty simple but the UX for the person you are sharing with is a little vague.

If you want to share:

- Select the dataset
- Select Share Dataset
- Choose an email, google group, etc.
- For data access only (w/o ability to run jobs on your project - so you're not billed for queries they make) choose the `BigQuery Data Viewer` role.

All this explained here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls

Once this is done, the user you shared with **will be able to run queries** on the dataset BUT will **not be able to view your project and dataset listed** under their data resources on left hand side of BQ console.

This is because you've provided them IAM access to the dataset and not the project (which is the correct way to do it).
If they want to see the project/dataset listed they need to pin the shared project/project to their project in BQ console:

1. They should enter the BQ URL for the sharing project: `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=[SHARING_PROJECT_NAME]`
2. Select the project on the data resource browser on the left and select PIN PROJECT
3. Go back to their original project on BQ console and will now see the shared project listed there as well.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That's not intuitive at all... Would be nice to get a notification  telling you that a new project is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can share the dataset with a service account which is in ***any*** project. 
I think you can do the same with regular user accounts without adding to the project.
https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/concepts/cross-bq-datasets

From BigQuery webconsole "share dataset" option:
You can share with these type of accounts

```
Google Account email: user@gmail.com
Google Group: admins@googlegroups.com
Service account: server@example.gserviceaccount.com
Google Apps domain: example.com
anybody: enter "allUsers" to grant access to the general public
all Google Accounts: enter "allAuthenticatedUsers" to grant access to any user signed in to a G[![enter image description here][1]][1]oogle Account (warning: shares publicly with users outside of your organization)
```